# Read precise time from simcard

Tags: android

I searched internet and found no result. could someone tell me if it's possible to get precise time from simcard or not? 
All I found was getting time from GPS and internet, but I want to get the exact time offline. not using any active connection.

Answer (score 1):

How would you get the exact time if you don't have some source to confirm what time it is?  You need to use one or the other.  Your only other option is to hope that the system time is correct, which is probably good enough-  most phones are set to sync time from the cellular network, so even if its offline briefly it won't be off by more than a few milliseconds.  If that isn't accurate enough, then you need to use cellular or GPS time.

Comment: If "easily over a hundred" falls within your definition of "a few milliseconds"...  This is something that varies a lot between devices, builds, and most likely carriers and locations as well.  Also be aware that the time can jump (including backwards) when a network/gps source becomes available.

Comment: It depends on how long it was offline and how good your hardware is of course.  Error is cumulative over time.  But being briefly offline won't cause much of a clock skew, definitely not that much.  TO get a 100 ms skew I'd expect it to be off for a few days.

Comment: Practical experience shows you would be mistaken in that assumption - for one, you are assuming that you started out with a perfect synchronization to an accurate source, which seems often not to be the case in practice - often you get jumps caused by imperfect synchronizations to a variety of imperfect sources.  And then there are devices where due to system software bugs, the monotonic clock isn't.

Comment: cellular you mean simcard ,right? I don't want to make simcard connect to internet, I just want to receive time offline.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no way to get the current time from a SIM card. This is because the SIM card does not have the time.